# asp.net ajax update panel

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have an asp.net webpage and im also using ajax with a timer trigger set to refresh every 5 seconds.  I have a few tables under update panel with a background image.  Everything works fine except that the first time it updates, the table images flickers.  After that, it will not flicker when it updates.  Any ideas??

Comment: Perhaps you can accept a few of the answers to your 35 questions if you want people to help.

Answer (score 0):

i think this occurs as backgroung image takes time to loads. Please keep the background iamge with minimum size as possible and also add the Single html image some where on the page with image as hidden. So that it always be there on page and no need to be reloaded each and every time.